# jQuery - Image Uploader for src and background-image

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

I have an image uploader working for images using `src` but if I change the image to a `div` with a `background-image` the uploader can't read the file as it isn't from src.

I want to upload the image as `background-image` for the `.uploader--bg` and as `src` for `.uploader--src`.

Currently only the second uploader works where the file-image is an image with src. How can I enable the first uploader that uses `background-image` instead of `img` `src`?

```js
$(function() {
  $(".file-drag").click(function(event) {
    $(this).siblings(".file-upload").click();
  });
  $(".uploader--src").each(function() {
    var imageNote = $(this).find(".start"),
      image = $(this).find(".file-image");
    if (image.attr("src").length > 0) {
      imageNote.addClass("hidden");
      image.removeClass("hidden");
    } else {
      imageNote.removeClass("hidden");
      image.addClass("hidden");
    }
  });
  $(".uploader--bg").each(function() {
    var imageNote = $(this).find(".start"),
      image = $(this).find(".file-image"),
      imageBg = $(this).closest(".uploader--bg").find(".file-image");
    if (imageBg.css("background-image") != "") {
      imageNote.addClass("hidden");
      imageBg.removeClass("hidden");
    } else {
      imageNote.removeClass("hidden");
      imageBg.addClass("hidden");
    }
  });

  function ekUpload(item) {
    var form = $(this).find("form.uploader"),
      fileSelect = $(this).find(".file-upload"),
      fileDrag = $(this).find(".file-drag"),
      submitButton = $(this).find(".submit-button");

    function Init() {
      $(document).on("change", "form", function(e) {
        fileSelectHandler(e);
      });

      // Is XHR2 available?
      var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
      if (xhr.upload) {
        if (isAdvancedUpload) {
          $(document)
            .on(
              "drag dragstart dragend dragover dragenter dragleave",
              "form",
              function(e) {
                // fileDragHover(e);
                e.preventDefault();
                e.stopPropagation();
              }
            )
            .on("dragover dragenter", "form", function(e) {
              e.preventDefault();
              e.stopPropagation();
              $(e.target).addClass("is-dragover");
            })
            .on("dragleave dragend drop", "form", function(e) {
              e.preventDefault();
              e.stopPropagation();
              $(e.target).removeClass("is-dragover");
            })
            .on("drop dragover", "body", function(e) {
              e.preventDefault();
              e.stopPropagation();
            })
            .on("drop", "form", function(e) {
              e.preventDefault();
              e.stopPropagation();
              fileSelectHandler(e);
            });
        }
      }
    }

    function fileDragHover(e) {
      e.stopPropagation();
      e.preventDefault();
      e.target.className =
        e.type === "dragover" ? "hover" : "modal-body file-upload";
    }

    async function fileSelectHandler(e) {
      var theForm = $(e.target).parent("form.uploader");

      var files = e.target.files || e.originalEvent.dataTransfer.files;

      // Process all File objects
      for (let i = 0; i < files.length; i++) {
        const f = files[i];
        if (
          theForm.closest(".checkalpha").length === 0 ||
          (await hasAlpha(f))
        ) {
          parseFile(f, theForm);
          uploadFile(f, theForm);
        } else {
          $(theForm)
            .closest(".checkalpha")
            .find(".response, .error-image")
            .removeClass("hidden");
          $(theForm).find(".file-image, .start").addClass("hidden");
          output(
            '<strong class="warning">Image background is not transparent</strong>'
          );
        }
      }
    }

    // Output
    function output(msg) {
      // Response
      var m = $(item).find(".message");
      m.html(msg);
    }

    function hasAlpha(file) {
      return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        let hasAlpha = false;
        const canvas = document.querySelector("canvas");
        const ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");

        const img = new Image();
        img.crossOrigin = "Anonymous";
        img.onerror = reject;
        img.onload = function() {
          canvas.width = img.width;
          canvas.height = img.height;

          ctx.drawImage(img, 0, 0);
          const imgData = ctx.getImageData(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height)
            .data;

          for (let j = 0; j < imgData.length; j += 4) {
            if (imgData[j + 3] < 255) {
              hasAlpha = true;
              break;
            }
          }
          resolve(hasAlpha);
        };
        img.src = URL.createObjectURL(file);
      });
    }

    function parseFile(file, thisForm) {
      output("<strong>" + encodeURI(file.name) + "</strong>");

      // var fileType = file.type;
      // console.log(fileType);
      var imageName = file.name;

      var isGood = /\.(?=svg|jpg|png|jpeg)/gi.test(imageName);
      if (isGood) {
        $(thisForm).find(".start, .notimage").addClass("hidden");
        $(thisForm).closest(".checkalpha").find(".response").addClass("hidden");
        $(thisForm).find(".error-image").addClass("hidden");
        $(thisForm)
          .find("label.has-advanced-upload")
          .removeClass("has-advanced-upload");
        $(thisForm)
          .find(".file-image")
          .removeClass("hidden")
          .attr("src", URL.createObjectURL(file));
      } else {
        $(thisForm).find(".error-image").removeClass("hidden");
        $(thisForm)
          .closest(".checkalpha")
          .find(".response, .file-image")
          .addClass("hidden");
        $(thisForm).find(".file-upload-form").trigger("reset");
        $(thisForm)
          .find('label[for="file-upload"]')
          .addClass("has-advanced-upload");
      }
    }

    function uploadFile(file, thisForm) {
      var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest(),
        fileSizeLimit = 1024; // in MB

      if (xhr.upload) {
        // Check if file is less than x MB
        if (file.size <= fileSizeLimit * 1024 * 1024) {
          // File received / failed
          xhr.onreadystatechange = function(e) {
            if (xhr.readyState == 4) {
              // Everything is good!
            }
          };

          // Start upload
          xhr.open(
            "POST",
            $(thisForm).find(".file-upload-form").attr("action"),
            true
          );
          xhr.setRequestHeader("X-File-Name", file.name);
          xhr.setRequestHeader("X-File-Size", file.size);
          xhr.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", "multipart/form-data");
          xhr.send(file);
        } else {
          output("Please upload a smaller file (< " + fileSizeLimit + " MB).");
        }
      }
    }

    // Check for the various File API support.
    if (window.File && window.FileList && window.FileReader) {
      Init();
    } else {
      document.getElementById("file-drag").style.display = "none";
    }
  }

  var isAdvancedUpload = (function() {
    var div = document.createElement("div");
    return (
      ("draggable" in div || ("ondragstart" in div && "ondrop" in div)) &&
      "FormData" in window &&
      "FileReader" in window
    );
  })();

  if (isAdvancedUpload) {
    $(".file-drag").addClass("has-advanced-upload");
  }

  $(".uploader").each(function() {
    ekUpload(this);
  });
});
```

```css
@import url(https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.5.0/css/font-awesome.min.css);
@import url("https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto");
body {
  padding: 2rem;
  background: #f8f8f8;
}

img.error-image {
  max-height: 160px;
}

.uploader {
  display: block;
  clear: both;
  margin: 0 auto;
  width: 100%;
  max-width: 600px;
}

.uploader label {
  float: left;
  clear: both;
  width: 100%;
  padding: 2rem 1.5rem;
  text-align: center;
  background: #fff;
  border-radius: 7px;
  border: 3px solid #eee;
  transition: all 0.2s ease;
  -webkit-user-select: none;
  -moz-user-select: none;
  -ms-user-select: none;
  user-select: none;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.uploader label.has-advanced-upload {
  background-color: white;
  outline: 2px dashed lightgrey;
  outline-offset: -10px;
}

.uploader label:hover {
  border: 3px solid #454cad;
  box-shadow: inset 0 0 0 6px #eee;
}

.uploader label.is-dragover,
.uploader label.is-dragover:hover {
  background-color: #eef;
}

.uploader label:hover {
  border: 3px solid #454cad;
  box-shadow: inset 0 0 0 6px #eee;
}

.uploader label:hover .start i.fa {
  -webkit-transform: scale(0.8);
  transform: scale(0.8);
  opacity: 0.3;
}

.uploader .start {
  float: left;
  clear: both;
  width: 100%;
  pointer-events: none;
}

.uploader .start.hidden {
  display: none;
}

.uploader .start i.fa {
  font-size: 50px;
  margin-bottom: 1rem;
  transition: all 0.2s ease-in-out;
}

.uploader .response {
  float: left;
  clear: both;
  width: 100%;
}

.uploader .response.hidden {
  display: none;
}

.uploader .response .messages {
  margin-bottom: 0.5rem;
}

.uploader .file-image {
  pointer-events: none;
  margin: 0 auto 0.5rem auto;
  width: auto;
  height: auto;
  max-width: 180px;
}

.uploader--bg .file-image {
  border-radius: 9px;
  min-height: 120px !important;
  min-width: 120px !important;
  padding: 0 0.6rem;
  background-size: cover !important;
  background-repeat: no-repeat !important;
  background-position: center !important;
}

.uploader .file-image.hidden {
  display: none;
}

.uploader .notimage {
  display: block;
  float: left;
  clear: both;
  width: 100%;
}

.uploader .notimage.hidden {
  display: none;
}

.uploader progress,
.uploader .progress {
  display: inline;
  clear: both;
  margin: 0 auto;
  width: 100%;
  max-width: 180px;
  height: 8px;
  border: 0;
  border-radius: 4px;
  background-color: #eee;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.uploader .progress[value]::-webkit-progress-bar {
  border-radius: 4px;
  background-color: #eee;
}

.uploader .progress[value]::-webkit-progress-value {
  background: linear-gradient(to right, #393f90 0%, #454cad 50%);
  border-radius: 4px;
}

.uploader .progress[value]::-moz-progress-bar {
  background: linear-gradient(to right, #393f90 0%, #454cad 50%);
  border-radius: 4px;
}

.uploader input[type="file"] {
  display: none;
}

.uploader div {
  margin: 0 0 0.5rem 0;
  color: #5f6982;
}

.uploader .btn {
  display: inline-block;
  margin: 0.5rem 0.5rem 1rem 0.5rem;
  clear: both;
  font-family: inherit;
  font-weight: 700;
  font-size: 14px;
  text-decoration: none;
  text-transform: initial;
  border: none;
  border-radius: 0.2rem;
  outline: none;
  padding: 0 1rem;
  height: 36px;
  line-height: 36px;
  color: #fff;
  transition: all 0.2s ease-in-out;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  background: #454cad;
  border-color: #454cad;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.uploader input[type="file"],
.hidden {
  display: none;
}

input[type="file"].hidden {
  display: block;
  width: 0.1px;
  height: 0.1px;
  opacity: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
  position: absolute;
  z-index: -1;
}

.warning {
  color: red;
  font-weight: bold;
}

canvas {
  position: absolute;
  top: -2000px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!-- Upload  -->
<div class="">
  <form class="file-upload-form uploader uploader--bg">
    <input class="file-upload" type="file" name="fileUpload" accept="image/*" />
    <label for="file-upload" class="file-drag">
      <div class="file-image" style="background-image: url('https://uploads-ssl.webflow.com/59df9e77ad9420000140eafe/5d379cfa511d417099a53de4_Giraffe_Couple_In_Love_600.jpg');"></div>
      <img class="error-image hidden" src="https://cdn3.iconfinder.com/data/icons/online-states/150/Snooze-512.png">
      <div class="start">
        <i class="fa fa-download" aria-hidden="true"></i>
        <div>Select a file or drag here</div>
        <div class="notimage hidden">Please select an image</div>
      </div>
      <div class="response hidden">
        <div class="message"></div>
      </div>
    </label>
  </form>
  <div class="filename"></div>
  <canvas></canvas>
</div>
<div class="checkalpha">
  <form class="file-upload-form uploader uploader--src">
    <input class="file-upload" type="file" name="fileUpload" accept="image/*" />
    <label for="file-upload" class="file-drag">
      <img class="file-image" src="" alt="Preview">
      <img class="error-image hidden" src="https://cdn3.iconfinder.com/data/icons/online-states/150/Snooze-512.png">
      <div class="start">
        <i class="fa fa-download" aria-hidden="true"></i>
        <div>Select a file or drag here</div>
        <div class="notimage hidden">Please select an image</div>
      </div>
      <div class="response hidden">
        <div class="message"></div>
      </div>
    </label>
  </form>
  <div class="filename"></div>
  <canvas></canvas>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way of doing this is by editing your `parseFile` to take into consideration the use of `background-image` rather than the `src` attribute.

```
if($(thisForm).find(".file-image").css("background-image") != "none") {
    $(thisForm)
       .find(".file-image")
       .css("background-image", "url("+URL.createObjectURL(file)+")");
} else {
    $(thisForm)
       .find(".file-image")
       .removeClass("hidden")
       .attr("src", URL.createObjectURL(file));
}
```

```js
$(function() {
  $(".file-drag").click(function(event) {
    $(this).siblings(".file-upload").click();
  });
  $(".uploader--src").each(function() {
    var imageNote = $(this).find(".start"),
      image = $(this).find(".file-image");
    if (image.attr("src").length > 0) {
      imageNote.addClass("hidden");
      image.removeClass("hidden");
    } else {
      imageNote.removeClass("hidden");
      image.addClass("hidden");
    }
  });
  $(".uploader--bg").each(function() {
    var imageNote = $(this).find(".start"),
      image = $(this).find(".file-image"),
      imageBg = $(this).closest(".uploader--bg").find(".file-image");
    if (imageBg.css("background-image") != "") {
      imageNote.addClass("hidden");
      imageBg.removeClass("hidden");
    } else {
      imageNote.removeClass("hidden");
      imageBg.addClass("hidden");
    }
  });

  function ekUpload(item) {
    var form = $(this).find("form.uploader"),
      fileSelect = $(this).find(".file-upload"),
      fileDrag = $(this).find(".file-drag"),
      submitButton = $(this).find(".submit-button");

    function Init() {
      $(document).on("change", "form", function(e) {
        fileSelectHandler(e);
      });

      // Is XHR2 available?
      var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
      if (xhr.upload) {
        if (isAdvancedUpload) {
          $(document)
            .on(
              "drag dragstart dragend dragover dragenter dragleave",
              "form",
              function(e) {
                // fileDragHover(e);
                e.preventDefault();
                e.stopPropagation();
              }
            )
            .on("dragover dragenter", "form", function(e) {
              e.preventDefault();
              e.stopPropagation();
              $(e.target).addClass("is-dragover");
            })
            .on("dragleave dragend drop", "form", function(e) {
              e.preventDefault();
              e.stopPropagation();
              $(e.target).removeClass("is-dragover");
            })
            .on("drop dragover", "body", function(e) {
              e.preventDefault();
              e.stopPropagation();
            })
            .on("drop", "form", function(e) {
              e.preventDefault();
              e.stopPropagation();
              fileSelectHandler(e);
            });
        }
      }
    }

    function fileDragHover(e) {
      e.stopPropagation();
      e.preventDefault();
      e.target.className =
        e.type === "dragover" ? "hover" : "modal-body file-upload";
    }

    async function fileSelectHandler(e) {
      var theForm = $(e.target).parent("form.uploader");

      var files = e.target.files || e.originalEvent.dataTransfer.files;

      // Process all File objects
      for (let i = 0; i < files.length; i++) {
        const f = files[i];
        parseFile(f, theForm);
        uploadFile(f, theForm);
      }
    }

    // Output
    function output(msg) {
      // Response
      var m = $(item).find(".message");
      m.html(msg);
    }

    function hasAlpha(file) {
      return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        let hasAlpha = false;
        const canvas = document.querySelector("canvas");
        const ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");

        const img = new Image();
        img.crossOrigin = "Anonymous";
        img.onerror = reject;
        img.onload = function() {
          canvas.width = img.width;
          canvas.height = img.height;

          ctx.drawImage(img, 0, 0);
          const imgData = ctx.getImageData(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height)
            .data;

          for (let j = 0; j < imgData.length; j += 4) {
            if (imgData[j + 3] < 255) {
              hasAlpha = true;
              break;
            }
          }
          resolve(hasAlpha);
        };
        img.src = URL.createObjectURL(file);
      });
    }

    function parseFile(file, thisForm) {
      output("<strong>" + encodeURI(file.name) + "</strong>");

      // var fileType = file.type;
      // console.log(fileType);
      var imageName = file.name;

      var isGood = /\.(?=svg|jpg|png|jpeg)/gi.test(imageName);
      if (isGood) {
        $(thisForm).find(".start, .notimage").addClass("hidden");
        $(thisForm).closest(".checkalpha").find(".response").addClass("hidden");
        $(thisForm).find(".error-image").addClass("hidden");
        $(thisForm)
          .find("label.has-advanced-upload")
          .removeClass("has-advanced-upload");
        if ($(thisForm).find(".file-image").css("background-image") != "none") {
          $(thisForm)
            .find(".file-image")
            .css("background-image", "url(" + URL.createObjectURL(file) + ")");
        } else {
          $(thisForm)
            .find(".file-image")
            .removeClass("hidden")
            .attr("src", URL.createObjectURL(file));
        }
      } else {
        $(thisForm).find(".error-image").removeClass("hidden");
        $(thisForm)
          .closest(".checkalpha")
          .find(".response, .file-image")
          .addClass("hidden");
        $(thisForm).find(".file-upload-form").trigger("reset");
        $(thisForm)
          .find('label[for="file-upload"]')
          .addClass("has-advanced-upload");
      }
    }

    function uploadFile(file, thisForm) {
      var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest(),
        fileSizeLimit = 1024; // in MB

      if (xhr.upload) {
        // Check if file is less than x MB
        if (file.size <= fileSizeLimit * 1024 * 1024) {
          // File received / failed
          xhr.onreadystatechange = function(e) {
            if (xhr.readyState == 4) {
              // Everything is good!
            }
          };

          // Start upload
          xhr.open(
            "POST",
            $(thisForm).find(".file-upload-form").attr("action"),
            true
          );
          xhr.setRequestHeader("X-File-Name", file.name);
          xhr.setRequestHeader("X-File-Size", file.size);
          xhr.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", "multipart/form-data");
          xhr.send(file);
        } else {
          output("Please upload a smaller file (< " + fileSizeLimit + " MB).");
        }
      }
    }

    // Check for the various File API support.
    if (window.File && window.FileList && window.FileReader) {
      Init();
    } else {
      document.getElementById("file-drag").style.display = "none";
    }
  }

  var isAdvancedUpload = (function() {
    var div = document.createElement("div");
    return (
      ("draggable" in div || ("ondragstart" in div && "ondrop" in div)) &&
      "FormData" in window &&
      "FileReader" in window
    );
  })();

  if (isAdvancedUpload) {
    $(".file-drag").addClass("has-advanced-upload");
  }

  $(".uploader").each(function() {
    ekUpload(this);
  });
});
```

```css
@import url(https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.5.0/css/font-awesome.min.css);
@import url("https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto");
body {
  padding: 2rem;
  background: #f8f8f8;
}

img.error-image {
  max-height: 160px;
}

.uploader {
  display: block;
  clear: both;
  margin: 0 auto;
  width: 100%;
  max-width: 600px;
}

.uploader label {
  float: left;
  clear: both;
  width: 100%;
  padding: 2rem 1.5rem;
  text-align: center;
  background: #fff;
  border-radius: 7px;
  border: 3px solid #eee;
  transition: all 0.2s ease;
  -webkit-user-select: none;
  -moz-user-select: none;
  -ms-user-select: none;
  user-select: none;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.uploader label.has-advanced-upload {
  background-color: white;
  outline: 2px dashed lightgrey;
  outline-offset: -10px;
}

.uploader label:hover {
  border: 3px solid #454cad;
  box-shadow: inset 0 0 0 6px #eee;
}

.uploader label.is-dragover,
.uploader label.is-dragover:hover {
  background-color: #eef;
}

.uploader label:hover {
  border: 3px solid #454cad;
  box-shadow: inset 0 0 0 6px #eee;
}

.uploader label:hover .start i.fa {
  -webkit-transform: scale(0.8);
  transform: scale(0.8);
  opacity: 0.3;
}

.uploader .start {
  float: left;
  clear: both;
  width: 100%;
  pointer-events: none;
}

.uploader .start.hidden {
  display: none;
}

.uploader .start i.fa {
  font-size: 50px;
  margin-bottom: 1rem;
  transition: all 0.2s ease-in-out;
}

.uploader .response {
  float: left;
  clear: both;
  width: 100%;
}

.uploader .response.hidden {
  display: none;
}

.uploader .response .messages {
  margin-bottom: 0.5rem;
}

.uploader .file-image {
  pointer-events: none;
  margin: 0 auto 0.5rem auto;
  width: auto;
  height: auto;
  max-width: 180px;
}

.uploader--bg .file-image {
  border-radius: 9px;
  min-height: 120px !important;
  min-width: 120px !important;
  padding: 0 0.6rem;
  background-size: cover !important;
  background-repeat: no-repeat !important;
  background-position: center !important;
}

.uploader .file-image.hidden {
  display: none;
}

.uploader .notimage {
  display: block;
  float: left;
  clear: both;
  width: 100%;
}

.uploader .notimage.hidden {
  display: none;
}

.uploader progress,
.uploader .progress {
  display: inline;
  clear: both;
  margin: 0 auto;
  width: 100%;
  max-width: 180px;
  height: 8px;
  border: 0;
  border-radius: 4px;
  background-color: #eee;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.uploader .progress[value]::-webkit-progress-bar {
  border-radius: 4px;
  background-color: #eee;
}

.uploader .progress[value]::-webkit-progress-value {
  background: linear-gradient(to right, #393f90 0%, #454cad 50%);
  border-radius: 4px;
}

.uploader .progress[value]::-moz-progress-bar {
  background: linear-gradient(to right, #393f90 0%, #454cad 50%);
  border-radius: 4px;
}

.uploader input[type="file"] {
  display: none;
}

.uploader div {
  margin: 0 0 0.5rem 0;
  color: #5f6982;
}

.uploader .btn {
  display: inline-block;
  margin: 0.5rem 0.5rem 1rem 0.5rem;
  clear: both;
  font-family: inherit;
  font-weight: 700;
  font-size: 14px;
  text-decoration: none;
  text-transform: initial;
  border: none;
  border-radius: 0.2rem;
  outline: none;
  padding: 0 1rem;
  height: 36px;
  line-height: 36px;
  color: #fff;
  transition: all 0.2s ease-in-out;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  background: #454cad;
  border-color: #454cad;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.uploader input[type="file"],
.hidden {
  display: none;
}

input[type="file"].hidden {
  display: block;
  width: 0.1px;
  height: 0.1px;
  opacity: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
  position: absolute;
  z-index: -1;
}

.warning {
  color: red;
  font-weight: bold;
}

canvas {
  position: absolute;
  top: -2000px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!-- Upload  -->
<div class="">
  <form class="file-upload-form uploader uploader--bg">
    <input class="file-upload" type="file" name="fileUpload" accept="image/*" />
    <label for="file-upload" class="file-drag">
      <div class="file-image" style="background-image: url('https://uploads-ssl.webflow.com/59df9e77ad9420000140eafe/5d379cfa511d417099a53de4_Giraffe_Couple_In_Love_600.jpg');"></div>
      <img class="error-image hidden" src="https://cdn3.iconfinder.com/data/icons/online-states/150/Snooze-512.png">
      <div class="start">
        <i class="fa fa-download" aria-hidden="true"></i>
        <div>Select a file or drag here</div>
        <div class="notimage hidden">Please select an image</div>
      </div>
      <div class="response hidden">
        <div class="message"></div>
      </div>
    </label>
  </form>
  <div class="filename"></div>
  <canvas></canvas>
</div>
<div class="checkalpha">
  <form class="file-upload-form uploader uploader--src">
    <input class="file-upload" type="file" name="fileUpload" accept="image/*" />
    <label for="file-upload" class="file-drag">
      <img class="file-image" src="" alt="Preview">
      <img class="error-image hidden" src="https://cdn3.iconfinder.com/data/icons/online-states/150/Snooze-512.png">
      <div class="start">
        <i class="fa fa-download" aria-hidden="true"></i>
        <div>Select a file or drag here</div>
        <div class="notimage hidden">Please select an image</div>
      </div>
      <div class="response hidden">
        <div class="message"></div>
      </div>
    </label>
  </form>
  <div class="filename"></div>
  <canvas></canvas>
</div>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/91uqr258/

Comment: Looking to upload as `background-image` for the `.uploader--bg` and as `src` for `.uploader--src`.

Comment: @KyleUnderhill isn't that what's it already doing with my update? Check my snippet and tell me which part exactly is not working as it should for you.

Comment: The second uploader (`.uploader--src`) is uploading the image as a background-image where it should be the src. The first instance is fine.

Comment: @KyleUnderhill fixed, meant to write `.css("background-image") != "none"`

Comment: The images are now uploading as I had hoped except now the `src` image is no longer passing through the `hasAlpha()` function to check if it has a transparent background.

Comment: @KyleUnderhill I removed that part for testing purposes, you can easily add it back... Here I added it back in this fiddle, but I'll leave the answer with it removed for testing purposes. https://jsfiddle.net/fh97cqe3/

Answer (score 1):

If I understand this question properly, then you intend to find out what the image is. Let's write a function for this purpose:

```
function getImageLocation(element) {
    if (element.tagName.toLowerCase() === "img") {
        return element.src;
    }
    var rawSource = element.style["background-image"];
    //The raw value looks like url("somepath")
    //Let's extract somepath
    return rawSource.replace(`url("`, ``).replace(`url('`, ``).replace(`")`, ``).replace(`')`, ``);
}
```

This function expects Javascript elements. You can convert it into `jQuery` style if you want.

Comment: I would like the first uploader to work like the second does, but because the `file-image` in the second instance isn't an image element using `src`, I want the uploader to recognize that and upload the image to the `background-image` url.

Comment: @KyleUnderhill yes. Please read the function in this answer. You will see that it returns src if it's an img and otherwise gets the value of background-image, removes the unnecessary prefix and suffix from its value..

Comment: Are you able to post a working snippet? I'm wondering how to call your function in the uploader code.

Comment: @KyleUnderhill your code is long and it would be time consuming for me to read it all. Please let me know which is the exact line where you intended to call it and what did you intend to pass to it.

Comment: `async function fileSelectHandler(e) {` This is the part of the function that reads the file, checks parameters and then uploads the file. If that helps

Comment: @KyleUnderhill It would be time-consuming to read your code, we do not review long codes here on SO. Instead, please check this Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/zugr3o70/

Comment: It should show you how you can call the function. It alerts the background image that you need.

Comment: @KyleUnderhill have you checked the Fiddle? If so, please let me know if you have questions.